# How do you update a listview from information gathered in another activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I currently have a simple activity which has a button to create a note. When that button is clicked, it fires an intent to go to another activity which is a template for the information needed in that note.

What is the best way to hold onto the information from the template, close that activity and populate the initial activities listview with the template information?

If I intend to create a SQLite database to interact with the note listview items, will I need a content provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
What is the best way to hold onto the information [...] and populate the initial activities listview with the template information?
```

I would recommend using an SQLite Database.

```
Will I need a content provider?
```

It's not required. Content Providers are *often* used to share information to other applications.

So simply put,

1- Create a Class where you extend `SQLiteOpenHelper`. From here you control the Database Cycles.

2- Create a Class where you manage the aforementioned class, and read/write to the databse. I would probably make all methods in this class `static` So they can be accessed from different Activities, without having to instantiate all the time.

Then, Once the user creates a new note, and hits a 'Save' button for instance, you call the Manager Class to store the new note data in the database. When The initial activity is restored (the one hosting the ListView) you can simply update the Cursor that is being used to populate the ListView.

Make sure that you are using a CursorAdapter btw.

For a simple example, you can see the following two classes: (Note: Comments in the class methods are in spanish).

- [Database Open Helper.](https://github.com/daniel-c05/RAEMovil/blob/master/src/com/lazybits/rae/movil/utils/DBHelper.java)
- [Database Manager.](https://github.com/daniel-c05/RAEMovil/blob/master/src/com/lazybits/rae/movil/utils/DbManager.java)